# Why do you gain access to moderator tools before marking a question as protected?

Tags: discussion, moderation, privileges, protected-questions

- 4,000 trusted user Expanded editing, deletion and undeletion privileges
- 3,500 protect questions Mark questions as protected
- 2,000 access to moderator tools Access reports, delete questions, review reviews

I was just wondering if there's a reason to this because it doesn't seem to be a logical order...

Moderator tools seen like they should be gained after achieving the protect questions privilege because protecting questions seems to be a smaller privilege and moderator tools sound like they should be worked for more than protecting questions.

If it were up to me I'd set it up do that you can mark question as protected at 2,000 and moderator tools at 2,500 but I don't know the underlying reasons for the current order.

Comment: A [protected question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question) has nothing to do with marking a question accepted. Could you explain a bit more why you think the order is illogical?

Comment: Why doesn't it seem to be logical? Is there any specific reason you think it should be changed, and to what?

Comment: @Jon Sorry about that... My mind must have wondered while typing the title. Fixed that.

Comment: @Door I added that in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> protecting questions seems to be a smaller privilege

Why do you think that?

In what sense does protection seem "smaller"? Upvoting and downvoting are both equally important, but the downvote privilege is higher than upvote. Does this seem illogical, too? If not, why not?

Here's a few reasons that are more specific. For one thing, protection is unilateral, while it requires three or more delete votes to delete a question. (Also, Moderator Tools only lets you vote to delete *questions* that have been *closed for at least two days*. You get more deletevote power at Trusted User.) Secondly, the ability to view deleted posts is not as prone to abuse as protecting a question is. Protection should be reserved for only exceptional situations where a question is getting an unusual amount of low quality answers, while the ability to simply see more information is less significant.

Comment: Ah, thank you, this makes sense. I knew there had to be a logical reason behind it.

Comment: Should I accept this? How does accepting work on meta?

Comment: @warspyking There's another reason, too; the system actively makes a strong effort to show you how things work first before giving you the power to use them. As Doorknob notes, protecting questions is actually a relatively powerful ability, and using the [mod tools](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tools), you can see which questions are protected before protecting them yourself. Re: accepting on meta; whatever helped you most.